# Using pagination for listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, pagination

I want to use pagination for a listview in android.I am loading 10 values at a time from a web service.But the problem is that the group of 10 values keep repeating.I have used an array list called `ice_data` for the adapter of the listview.The code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    public HttpResponse video_respons;
    public String video_string_response1;
    public ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs_Video;
    ArrayList<Ice_data> ice_list;
    String URL="http://footballultimate.com/icebucket/index.php/api/getVideo";
    String URL1="http://footballultimate.com/icebucket/index.php/api/getVideoByLimit";
    JSONObject jsonobj;
    JSONArray jsonarr;
    Ice_data iceobj;
    CustomIceAdapter ciadp;
    ListView list;
    int start = 1;
     int limit = 10;
     boolean loadingMore = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();
        // GEt all Data for Video
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(VideoActivity.this);
        Config.isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (!Config.isInternetPresent) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoActivity.this);
            // Shuld be fail icon
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage("Connection Not Available !" + "\n"
                    + "Please enable your Internet Connection");
            builder.setTitle("INTERNET CONNECTION");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            new GetVideos().execute();
        }
        // Get all Data for Video
         list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videoList);
        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;   
                   if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){    

                       new GetVideos().execute();
                   }

            }
        });
    }


    class GetVideos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private HttpResponse vip_respons;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            loadingMore = true;
            //ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL1);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start",String.valueOf(start)));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit",String.valueOf(limit)));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                video_respons = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                //video_string_response1 = getResponseBody(video_respons);
                video_string_response1=responsetostring.getResponseBody(video_respons);
                //Log.d("Store_Response", the_string_response1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String video_string) {
            try{
                   if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                       pDialog.dismiss();
                   }  
            }
          catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally
          {
              pDialog.dismiss();
          }
            if (video_string_response1!=null) {
                //displayjsonstring();
                geticevalues(video_string_response1);

            }
        }
    }

    public void geticevalues(String result)
    {

        try {
            jsonobj=new JSONObject(result);
            //ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();
            jsonarr=jsonobj.getJSONArray("video_data");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jso=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                iceobj=new Ice_data();
                iceobj.title=jso.getString("title");
                iceobj.image_URL=jso.getString("image");
                iceobj.video_URL=jso.getString("url");
                ice_list.add(iceobj);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ciadp=new CustomIceAdapter(VideoActivity.this,ice_list);
        loadingMore = false;
        ciadp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(ciadp);
        start+=10;
    }
```

How do i prevent the duplication of the values in the listview.?

Comment: have you check second page response data i think may be came same in second page also then is possible other wise your code look nice.

Comment: But when i load the page first time itself two sets of the same data loads.That means the request to the webservice is going twice right at the beginning itself.

Comment: I think this happens becz when first time your list is empty list setOnScrollListener() called and your new GetVideos().execute(); executed two time first in else case and then setOnScrollListener() so  i think you debug setOnScrollListener() then you get exact idea.

Comment: i tried adding if(ice_data.size()!=0) in the scroll listener.The first set of values are not shown as duplicates.But the second set is shown with duplicates.How do i fix it?

Comment: try to debug ice_list value before given to adapter then you get exact idea what happens with ice_list data.

Comment: When i debug the code everything works fine.But when i run the code i get duplicates.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Any other help!!When i debug it the first set of values dont have duplicates then further down there are duplicates.

Comment: I tried using the get method , it works but the loading symbol in the preexecute is not being shown.